# How to sort a gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi i am using gridview for viewing data from database. now i need to sort it my code is bellow.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    GetDataTable();


}
public void GetDataTable()
{

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FacebookConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select Distinct F_Name AS [First Name], S_Name AS [Sur Name], E_Mail AS [Email], Day+'-'+Month+'-'+Year AS [Birthday], Gender AS [Gender] from Users ";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Users");
            dt.Load(dr);
            grdUser.DataSource = dt;
            grdUser.DataBind();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }

    }
}


protected void grdUser_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{

}


protected void grdUser_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdUser.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GetDataTable();
}
```

and aspx code is bellow

```
<div class="container" style="padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; margin-top:auto">

    <asp:GridView ID="grdUser" runat="server" CssClass="table table-responsive table-condensed table-striped table-hover" OnPageIndexChanging="grdUser_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="grdUser_Sorting" PageSize="3" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
        ForeColor="Black">
        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4" />


    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

I am new into programming i have tried many ways to do it but i m not getting any result please help

Comment: I need to sort it on bases of First Name only

Comment: When you say you are not getting any result, do you mean that the grid is completely empty?  If you set a breakpoint after you load the DataTable, does it have any data?  What happens if you execute your SQL query directly in SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
cmd.Connection = con;
 cmd.CommandText = "select Distinct F_Name AS [First Name], S_Name AS [Sur Name], E_Mail AS [Email], Day+'-'+Month+'-'+Year AS [Birthday], Gender AS [Gender] from Users order by F_Name ";
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ORDER BY Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) in your SQL Query. By default sort order is ascending. If you need to sort in descending order use `ORDER BY F_Name DESC`

```
SELECT DISTINCT F_Name AS [First Name]
    ,S_Name AS [Sur Name]
    ,E_Mail AS [Email]
    ,Day + '-' + Month + '-' + Year AS [Birthday]
    ,Gender AS [Gender]
FROM Users
ORDER BY F_Name
```